# Hadoop setup for 64 bit Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: hadoop

I have Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit OS. Do I need to download any specific Hadoop setup (i mean for 64 bit OS) or normally downloaded Hadoop setup will work fine??

Answer (score 1):

I just installed hadoop on my system..This might help you

http://mysolvedproblem.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Normal install is perfectly fine: [Single node setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html)